# Python C API: How to get PyRun_String with Py_eval_input to use imported modules?

Tags: python, python-c-api

```
PyRun_String("random.randint(1,10)", Py_eval_input, globals, globals);
```

returns error with:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
NameError: name 'random' is not defined
```

earlier in the code, I did:

```
PyImport_ImportModule("random");
```

I guess this is not the way to get it work.  What is the correct way?
Thank you!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`PyImport_ImportModule` returns the imported value. You need to save it in `globals` under the name `random`. In summary:

```
PyMapping_SetItemString(globals, "random", PyImport_ImportModule("random"));
```

but don't forget to also check the result of the import in case it throws an exception.